# How to make a surface over a closed area with the bsurface addon

Tags: add-on, topology, grease-pencil

Hello to every blender guru.

I'm trying to learn how the bsurface addon works. Let's say that I want to make a surface over the whole area highlighted in the picture below. Where you will make the cuts ?

[image: picture where I want to create a surface]

I wonder if it possible to modify the bsurface addon to improve his flexibility. It will be more useful if it was able to draw a closed area with the grease pencil tool and then fill it with a (b)surface. In other words,I don't want to make a grid or draw parallel strokes. I think that it could improves the creation process. What do you think ?